# Google Assistant - Air conditioner name bug

Tags: google-home, google-smart-home, google-assistant

I have AC and device name is TRIAL AC. When I try to change ac mode to off mode, it's successfully changing and google sends request for **thermostatMode:off** .
When I change device name without AC as TRIAL, I'm trying same command "set TRIAL to off" and google sends request as **on:off** so on/off state changes but thermostat mode still like previous.

Device name : **TRIAL AC**: set trial ac to off 
Google request
{"commands":[{"devices":[{"customData":{"availableFanModes":{"Auto":3,"High":2,"Low":0,"Medium":1},"availableModes":{"Auto":"3","Cool":"2","Dry":"5","Fan":"4","Off":"0"},"extendedServices":{},"services":{"FanService":"action.devices.commands.SetFanSpeed","OutletService":"action.devices.commands.OnOff","TemperatureService":"action.devices.commands.thermostatTemperatureAmbient","ThermostatModeService":"action.devices.commands.ThermostatSetMode","ThermostatService":"action.devices.commands.ThermostatTemperatureSetpoint"}},"id":"1023-0"}],"execution":[{"command":"action.devices.commands.ThermostatSetMode","params":{"thermostatMode":"off"}}]}]}

Device name : **TRIAL** : set trial ac to off 
Google request 2
{"commands":[{"devices":[{"customData":{"availableFanModes":{"Auto":3,"High":2,"Low":0,"Medium":1},"availableModes":{"Auto":"3","Cool":"2","Dry":"5","Fan":"4","Off":"0"},"extendedServices":{},"services":{"FanService":"action.devices.commands.SetFanSpeed","OutletService":"action.devices.commands.OnOff","TemperatureService":"action.devices.commands.thermostatTemperatureAmbient","ThermostatModeService":"action.devices.commands.ThermostatSetMode","ThermostatService":"action.devices.commands.ThermostatTemperatureSetpoint"}},"id":"1023-0"}],"execution":[{"command":"action.devices.commands.OnOff","params":{"on":false}}]}]}

Answer (score 0):

Google uses a Natural Language Understanding model that is analyzing the user requests and try to interpret what the user intends to achieve. When this system is working with any name that users can set for their device, it will choose the likeliest option from it’s knowledge base.

When you have a device type as part of the same (“AC”), the NLU seems to be giving a different result. We do not recommend including device types in the name.

The intended result for a “Set X to Off” command would be to trigger On/Off trait (rather than the Thermostat Mode). To change the mode of a device, you can try “Set X to Off Mode”. Also, note that you are using the On/Off trait with the Thermostat trait in the same device, which is something we do not recommend. For thermostats, our recommendation is to provide the ThermostatMode trait only.